# C# - Getting ManagementObjectSearcher to output to a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have the following code that grabs Scheduled Tasks, although I am having trouble outputting them into a text box:

```
private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ScheduledJob");
    var tasks = query.Get();
    richTextBox6.Text = ManagementObjectSearcher.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please explain the kind of trouble you are having.

Comment: Why are you trying to get the toString() representation of the ManagementObjectSearcher object? All this would return is the name of the component.

Comment: @Tim I am trying to get the output of the method, which is the Scheduled Tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
        var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ScheduledJob");
        var tasks = query.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject task in tasks)
        {
            richTextBox6.Text += Environment.NewLine + task["Description"]
        }
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but Textbox is usually not the right control for bound data.

Comment: @Mike Miller Which control do you recommend then?

Comment: @ Mike Miller I get Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection'

Comment: @Mike Miller Thanks, ill take a look, still getting the error above though :/

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ManagementObject task in tasks)
{
      Console.WriteLine(task.GetPropertyValue("Description"));
}
```

get properties from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394399%28VS.85%29.aspx)